# Graph Theory(Spanning Tree)

Tags: graph-theory, trees

[image]

How many spanning trees of the graph contain the edges QS and RS?

I am not so sure on how to solve this question because there are some many different spanning tree I suppose. Precisely how do I solve questions like this? Thank you.

Comment: Once you have $QS$ and $RS$, there are only two vertices left.  How many way do you have to extend the tree so as to add $P$?  How many for $T$?  How many in total?

Comment: There are not many. There are only 6 of them, so you can just count them.

Comment: But that is my problem i feel because I am not sure on how to find the spanning tree unless its something like from P to Q to R to S to T or like P to R to S to Q to T . So i am not sure if i am doing the right way to find it ?

Answer (score 1):

A spanning tree is a set of edges that connect all the vertices but don't create any cycles. Equivalently, you need exactly $n-1$ edges (where $n$ is the number of vertices) and a route from any vertex to any other.

Once you have QS and RS, you need two more edges. Also, Q, R and S are already connected to each other. So you need to connect P and T. Since there is no edge PT, the only way to do this is to use one edge to connect P to Q/R/S, and another to connect T to Q/R/S. There are $3$ choices for the first edge, but only $2$ for the second (since TR doesn't exist), so there are $6$ ways to make both choices.